# python Multiprocessing with ibm_db2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2, multiprocessing

I'm reading around 15 Million data from db2 LUW using python ibm_db2 module. I'm reading the data for every one million once and again reading this data in chunks to avoid memory issues. The problem here is to complete one loop of reading one million data its taking 4 Mins . How can i use multiprocessing to avoid delay . Blow is my code.

```
start =0
count = 15000000
check_point =  1000000

chunk_size = 100000
connection = get_db_conn_cur(secrets_db2)
for i in range(start, count, check_point): 
       query_str = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.timestamp) row_num, * from table a) where  row_num between " + str( i + 1) + " and " + str(i + check_point) + "" 
        
       number_of_batches = check_point // chunk_size
       last_chunk = check_point - (number_of_batches * chunk_size) 
       counter = 0 
       cur = connection.cursor()
       cur.execute(query_str) s
        
       chunk_size_l = chunk_size 
       while True:
         counter = counter + 1 
         columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description] 
         print('counter', counter)
         if counter > number_of_batches: 
              chunk_size_l = last_chunk 
         results = cur.fetchmany(chunk_size_l) 
         if not results:
            break 
         df = pd.DataFrame(results)
         #further processing
```

Comment: Why not process the bulk-data inside Db2, that should be faster than processing same data outside of the database. If you are taking the processed-data outside of Db2, better to process in Db2 (in unlogged session tables (dgtt)) and then either export or write to external-tables.

Comment: problem is we don't have control over DB2.

Comment: Why do you need control over Db2 to do elementary stuff like I suggest in my previous comment? Hint: no control is required. Just the correct access levels.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not multiprocessing. Is your approach to read data. As far as I can see, you're using ROW_NUMBER() just to number the rows and then fetch them 1 million rows per loop.

As you're not using any WHERE condition on `table a` this will result in a FULL TABLE SCAN every loop you're running. You are wasting too much CPU and I/O on Db2 server just to have a row number, and that's why it's taking 4 minutes or more each loop.

Also, this is far from a efficient way to fetch data. You can have duplicate reads or phantom reads as long as data changes during your program. But that is subject for another thread.

You should be using one of the 4 fetch methods described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054388.html) reading row by row from a SQL CURSOR. That way you'll be using a very small amount of RAM and can read data efficiently:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY a.timestamp"
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
dictionary = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)

while dictionary != False:
    dictionary = ibm_db.fetch_both(stmt)
```